# Retry Whole Batch Job for n times

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Is it possible to retry a particular job for say n times?

```
public void run() {

    String[] springConfig = { "spring/batch/jobs/job-read-files.xml" };
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);

    JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
    Job job = (Job) context.getBean("partitionJob");
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        try {
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job,jobParameters);
            System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getAllFailureExceptions());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Done");

}
```

I tried this, but since spring batch stores some status for job completion,it doesn't work in the second and third time.

Update: It worked when i tried this

```
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    String[] springConfig = { "spring/batch/jobs/job-read-files.xml" };
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);

    JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
    Job job = (Job) context.getBean("partitionJob");
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters();

        try {
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job,jobParameters);
            System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getAllFailureExceptions());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Done");

}
```

Is there a better solution than this?
Here is my job config

```
<!-- partitioner job -->
<job id="partitionJob" restartable="true"  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <!-- master step, 2 threads (grid-size) -->
    <step id="masterStep" next="finalstep">
            <partition step="slave" partitioner="rangePartitioner">
                <handler grid-size="2" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
            </partition>
    </step>
    <step id="finalstep">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="dummyReader" writer="spWriter" commit-interval="1" />
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>

<batch:step id="slave">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="pagingItemReader" writer="dummyWriter"
            commit-interval="2" retry-limit="3">
            <batch:retryable-exception-classes>
                <batch:include class="java.lang.Exception" />
            </batch:retryable-exception-classes>
        </chunk>
    </tasklet>
</batch:step>
```

Comment: Are you looking to retry a job (as in it fails and you want to restart it) or just run it multiple times?

Comment: Its like i have to retry the job for like n times , because I am trying to set some threshold values in remote devices over snmp protocol. Every time I run the job , it has to be retried n times .It will be like running the job for multiple times .

Comment: Description about each step . Master step will do the partitioning,slave step will read the db and do the pending jobs , final step will move the finished (successful) jobs to archive table(by using a stored procedure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring has nice retry mechanism, where you can define `RetryTemplate`, and you call some part of code `N` times, and you can define `RetryCallback` and `RecoveryCallback` which is nice.

Spring batch actually uses it internally for retry mechanism on step. You can checkout [spring retry documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/retry.html) and regarding retry on step level [this is nice blog post](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/03/transactions-in-spring-batch-part-3-skip-and-retry/) which explains skip and retry mechanism in spring batch.